# How do i fix error in seq issue on markdown?

Tags: r

Hi i keep getting this error code - Error in seq.int(from, to, length.out = n) : 'to' must be a finite number

My code is -

```
x<-seq(0,1, by=.001)
y<-dbeta(0.25, 4, 13)
curve(dbeta(x,4, 13), xlim = c(0.1), ylab = "", axes= F, ylim=x(0,4.5), xlab = "Pi")
cord.x<-c(0, seq(0,0.25,0.5), 0.25)
cord.y<-c(0, dbeta(seq(0,0.25,0.5), 4, 13), 0)
prob=pbeta(0.25,4,13)
polygon(cord.x,cord.y, col = "lightblue")
text(.3,4.3,paste("p(pi<0.25)=",round(prob,4)))
abline(h=0)
axis(1)
```

What do I do?

Comment: The `xlim` argument of `curve` needs to have length 2 - it needs to give both lower and upper limits. Change `xlim = c(0.1)` to, perhaps `xlim = c(0, 1)` (or whatever other values you want). When you fix that, you will still have an error with `ylim=x(0,4.5)`, try `ylim=c(0, 4.5)`.

Comment: Generally, I'd suggest running your code one line at a time and stopping at the first error...